# Prove that $n^2 - 2n + 7$ is even then $n + 1$ is even

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have to use Proof by contradiction to show what if $n^2 - 2n + 7$ is even then $n + 1$ is even.

Assume $n^2 - 2n + 7$ is even then $n + 1$ is odd. By definition of odd integers, we have $n = 2k+1$.

What I have done so far:

\begin{align}
& n + 1 = (2k+1)^2 - 2(2k+1) + 7 \\
\implies & (2k+1) = (4k^2+4k+1) - 4k-2+7-1 \\
\implies & 2k+1 = 4k^2+1-2+7-1 \\
\implies & 2k = 4k^2 + 4 \\
\implies & 2(2k^2-k+2) 
\end{align}

Now, this is even but I wanted to prove that this is odd(the contradiction). Can you some help me figure out my mistake?

Thank you.

Comment: Is it "when $n+1$ is even", or "then $n+1$ is even"? Both statements are remarkably different, hence clarification is sought.

Comment: hey it is "then n+1 is even".

Comment: we have $n + 1 = 2k + 1$ for some $k$, hence $n = 2k$, continue from here,

Comment: Wait: is $n+1$ even or odd? The title says different things to the post...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are doing a proof by contradiction, your start is:  Assume $n+1$ is odd. But if $n+1$ is odd, then $n$ is even, and so yo should plug in $n=2k$, rather than what you did, which was plugging in $2k+1$

Answer (score 1):

If $n + 1$ is even, then  $n$ must be odd. Let $n = 2k + 1$ since it is in the form of an odd number. Now substitute into the quadratic expression: $$\begin{align} n^2 - 2n + 7 &= (2k+1)^2 - 2(2k+1) + 7 \\ &= (2k)^2 + 1 + 4k - 4k - 2 + 7 \\ &= 4k^2 + 6 \\ &= 2(2k^2 + 3).\end{align}$$ Since the quadratic is an even number, this also completes the proof. For more sensibility, since $n + 1$ is even, we can let $n + 1 = 2r$ and then let $n = 2r - 1$, but the same is implied anyway.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out bt @Bram28 and others you use contradiction by making the appropriate changes.

However, I suggest that you try to use contrapositive instead of contradiction, whenever possible as it makes fewer assumptions.

The easiest (and cleanest) way to solve this is proving the contrapositive instead i.e. if $n+1$ is odd, then $n^2-2n+7$ is odd.

Since $n+1$ is odd, so $n$ is even and we can write $n=2k$ for some interger $k$.

Note that $n^2-2n+7=4k^2-4k+6+1=2(2k^2-2k+3)+1=2m+1$, where $m=2k^2-2k+3$ is an integer, proving the result.

Comment: I was asked to use contradiction. I didn't have a choice :P

Comment: I am just trying to give advice on how to think through a problem by checking through a hierarchy of proof techniques. It may not be very useful for this assignment but does provide the most optimal proof technique in this case for it makes lesser assumptions than a proof by contradiction.

Comment: yes i would also prefer contrapositive over this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> Prove that $n^2-2n+7$ is even *then* $n+1$ is even.

If $n^2-2n+7$ is even, then $n^2-2n$ is odd.

For all even numbers, this does not work since $(even)^2-2(even)$ always results in an even number.

Therefore, the number $n$ **must** be an odd number. Since $n$ is odd, $n+1$ is even.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Note that

- $n^2-2n+7=n^2-2n+1+6=(n-1)^2+6$ is even $\iff$ $n-1$ is even

and

- $n+1=(n-1)+2$

Answer (score 0):

$n^2-2n+7
=n^2+2n+1-(4n+6)
=(n+1)^2-2(2n+3)
$.

If this is even then,
since $2(2n+3)$ is even,
their sum is even,
so $(n+1)^2$ is even
so $n+1$ is even.